# ASP.NET 5 / MVC 6 Database First - No connection string named MyEntity could be found in the application config file

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

Our ASP.NET 5 / MVC 6 project accesses our DB by going through a Business layer assembly then down into DAL (Database First) assembly.  The MVC 6 code blows up when trying to execute the Business layer code which uses the DbContext to access the DB with error: No connection string named 'MyEntity' could be found in the application config file.  I have tried defining the MyEntity connection string in the MVC project config.json, appsettings.json in various ways with no luck.

If executing Business layer methods from a tester project where I have the expected app.config file with connection string syntax as below it works no problem.

**Note** This question could also be restated as how to migrate a MVC 5 to MVC 6 app, where the MVC 5 app loosely coupled DB access to DAL layer and the MVC code had NO knowledge of EF and ONLY supplied the web.config connection string needed by DbContext object in DAL?

Any help would be appreciated, let me know if you need any more information.

Config file syntax in Tester project:

```
<add name="MyEntity" 

connectionString="metadata=res://*/MyModel.csdl|res://*/MyModel.ssdl|res://*/MyModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=MyServer;initial catalog=MyDB;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Likely wrong syntax in config.json file.

```
{
  "Data": {

"defaultConnection": {

"connectionString": "metadata=res://*/MyModel.csdl|res://*/MyModel.ssdl|res://*/MyModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=MyServer;initial catalog=MyDB;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;"
    },

"entityFramework": {

"MyEntity": {

"ConnectionString": "name=data:defaultConnection:connectionString"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What does your Startup.cs look like? How is the database context created?

Answer (score 1):

How is the database context created?

[Migrate Configuration Settings from web.config](http://aspnetmvc.readthedocs.org/projects/mvc/en/latest/migration/migratingconfig.html#migrate-configuration-settings-from-web-config)

The connection string can be in appsettings.json

```
{
    "Data": {
        "DefaultConnection": {
            "ConnectionString": "Server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=_CHANGE_ME;Trusted_Connection=True;"
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit**
You can get your connection string as follows:

```
string connection = Configuration.Get<string>("Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString");
```

Comment: The database context was created via ADO.NET Entity Data Model wizard, EF Designer from database (existing DB)...  

Yeah i did try many variations such as the site you mentioned with no luck.

[Migrate Configuration Settings from web.config](http://aspnetmvc.readthedocs.org/projects/mvc/en/latest/migration/migratingconfig.html#migrate-configuration-settings-from-web-config)

Comment: Are you passing your connection string to the library or expecting the library to pick it up automatically? See my edit on how to get your connection string.

Answer (score 1):

Add a class in data layer as

```
public class ConfigHelper
{

    public static string ConnectionString { get; set; }

    public ConfigHelper(string conn )
    {
        ConnectionString = conn;

    }
}
```

Then in startup.cs

```
var connectionString = Configuration["Data:"Connectionstring name":ConnectionString"];
ConfigHelper.ConnectionString = connectionString;
```

now in

```
public partial class Context : DbContext
{
    public Context()
        : base(ConfigHelper.ConnectionString)
    {
    }
}
```

also another approach will be using dependency injection.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot Rami for your helpful hints, I was indeed relying on EF to pick up the connection string automatically.  This worked fine for MVC 5 (and previou versions) running with Database First model where we could specify the expected DB connection name, but with MVC 6 will need to pass in the connection string explicitly.

I added the additional ctor taking the connection string in its own partial class file, since we're doing Database First and the context file gets overwritten with successive model updates from DB.  I.e having in separate partial class / file preserves new ctor to not be overwritten.

```
public partial class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext(string connectionString)
        : base(connectionString)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Specifying connection in config.json did not work for me. 
We need to move the connection string from app.config file to the code. This can be done in context.cs file.
In the constructor you need to specify the connection string

```c#
public partial class ProducerCentralEntities : DbContext
    {
        public ProducerCentralEntities()
      : base(@"metadata = res://*/TestProj.csdl|res://*/TestProj.ssdl|res://*/TestProj.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=';data source=serverName;initial catalog=databaseName;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;application name=EntityFramework';")
        {
        }
      }
```

Note:
1) You should have complete connection string
2) Replace quote " with '

Answer (score 0):

Put the connection string in the app.config file.